# Particle between entangled particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Is a particle in between an entangled pair of two other particles affected if a measurenent is done on one of the entangled particles?

In other words. Do we know nothing happens in the space between the entangled particles?

Comment: What does "in between an entangled pair" mean? Quantum states usually do not have definite positions, so it is unclear what "in between" is supposed to denote.

Comment: In between were the two entangled particles are measured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a fairly abstract level, you can think of entanglement as some sort of interaction or coupling between between states. Entanglement is a special sort of interaction where if two particles A and B are very entangled, then it is necessarily true that the entanglement between A and C or B and C must be small (entanglement monogamy theorem).

If you have 3 particles (it doesnt matter their positions), if A and B are perfectly entangled, i.e. they are a maximally entangled state, then it must be true that A and C have no entanglement. Thus, a measurement on A should have no effect on C.

*Edit by suggestion: when I say that A and B are very entangled, I mean that the states have close to maximal entanglement entropy, and small entanglement to mean close to minimal entanglement entropy. Specifically there is an inequality condition where if A and B share some amount of entanglement, there is an upper limit on how much entanglement there can be between A and C*

Further reading [here](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8113/43/44/445305)

Similarly, we often model the environment as a sort of auxiliary state C which might have entanglement with our system. Thus, collapsing a state or external noise is "recorded" in the environment, although due to the complexity of C it cannot be recovered.

Comment: I think very and small entangled should be explained, the best with examples. And, if you Jeong San Kim, mark it as an annotation to the link  :-)

Comment: +1: This is a nice answer but I have a minor issue with it. While I see that you wanted to simplify the concept of entanglement for the OP, it can be misleading to say that entanglement can be seen as an interaction or coupling between the entangled systems. While it's true that you would need an interacting Hamiltonian between the two systems to get them entangled if they weren't entangled before, they'd remain entangled even after the interaction has been turned off. There is no interaction between the entangled systems as such.

Comment: In other words, entanglement is a property of the state itself (w.r.t. a factorization), it doesn't tell us anything about the Hamiltonian per se.

Comment: Does “ maximal entanglement entropy” means a statistical property after a lot of measured pairs of particles?

Answer (score 2):

In short, **yes**. Within the framework of quantum mechanics, we do know that nothing happens in the space between entangled particles. (Subject to the caveat that, as ACuriousMind pointed out, you can't really think of quantum objects as having any definite position.)

In a bit more detail: one of the most basic entangled states is the [Bell state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_state) $|\Psi_+ \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left(|0 \rangle_A |1 \rangle_B + |1 \rangle_A |0 \rangle_B \right)$. You can interpret this as saying Alice ($A$) has one particle and Bob ($B$) has the other, and **either** Alice has a particle in the $|0 \rangle$ state and Bob has a particle in the $|1 \rangle$ state, **or** Alice has a particle in the $|1 \rangle$ state and Bob has a particle in the $|0 \rangle$ state -- and until we measure, **we don't know which is true**! In fact, according to quantum mechanics -- until we make a measurement -- **both** are true at the same time.

Quantum mechanics tells you exactly **what** you might find after measuring. (Well, it tells you the probabilities of each possible measurement outcome.) But it tells you nothing about **how** that happened.

Let's look at the Bell state situation again. Alice gets one particle (in an unknown state) and Bob gets the other. They get in spaceships and travel to different galaxies. This whole time, Alice is carrying a particle in **both** the $|0 \rangle$ **and** the $|1 \rangle$ state, and Bob is carrying a particle that's in the **opposite** state to Alice's.

There are a number of different [interpretations of quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretations_of_quantum_mechanics) which completely reproduce the predictions of quantum mechanics*, but they all tell very different stories about how nature works. Some of them make extra predictions **beyond** standard quantum mechanics, meaning they are in principle testable. But at the moment, you can very roughly think of them all as being equivalent, for the purposes of gaining intuition about quantum mechanics. You can choose whichever story helps you best understand the given situation.

For situations like this Bell state measurement, I personally like using [retrocausality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrocausality). Very roughly -- experts would almost certainly disagree with this description, though -- retrocausality says that once Alice measures her particle, she **retrocausally** chooses the correct system evolution. That means if she measured a $|0 \rangle$, that **causes** the system to have evolved as **just** a $|0 \rangle$ for Alice and a $|1 \rangle$ for Bob the entire time.

In this view, it's clear nothing happened "between" the two particles when they were measured. Instead, whatever Alice measures, that means Bob measures the opposite, because that's the way the system has to be.

I want to stress, however, that until any given quantum mechanics interpretation is experimentally verified, they are **just intuitive tools** that say nothing about how reality really behaves. And if you want to be correct, you should always check your intuition mathematically.

**As Dvij D.C correctly points out in a comment, not all of the quantum mechanics interpretations can reproduce quantum field theory, which is a more fundamental theory of nature. That is a problem for those interpretations.*

Comment: _You can interpret this as saying Alice (A) gets one particle and Bob (B) gets the other, and either Alice has a |0⟩ state and Bob has a |1⟩ state, or Alice has a |1⟩ state and Bob has a |0⟩ state -- and until we measure, we don't know which is which!_ This is a bit problematic. It's not that _we_ don't know which is which, it's that until you measure, it's neither, it's a superposition.

Comment: Also, many of them seem experimentally testable (and are already tested). For example, any kind of classical model doesn't pass the experiential tests unless you adopt non-locality. Also, not all of them make equivalent predictions. GRW makes distinct predictions, for example. And it should be noted that only very few of the interpretations can be generalized to QFT.

Comment: Corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Entanglement describes only the relationship (or rather, what is known of it) between the entangled particles. It describes nothing else,

Answer (score -1):

> Is a particle in between an entangled pair of two other particles affected if a measurenent is done on one of the entangled particles?

For photons, **no**. Photons, even entangled, couldn’t influence another photon between them. These quanta are indivisible particles in the time between their emission and their absorption.

For electrons, **dependent**.

1. Every interaction of an electron with the measuring instrument changes its fields. Since the theory says that the electric and magnetic field of electrons is extended to infinity, the measuring device becomes something that is located between two entangled electrons. Or, at least, the device influences the space (the fields) between the two particles. So theoretically, for electrons (which always move at a lower speed of light), **yes**, alternating electric and magnetic fields reach the second electron.
2. In practice entangled particles are under the constant influence of the environment and it is the task to protect them from these influences or/and to filter out statistically those cases which are no longer entangled. But, **no**, practically nobody takes into account the influence of the measuring instrument on the second electron. It is simply not observable.

> In other words. Do we know nothing happens in the space between the entangled particles?

We only know that in the case of double-slit experiments, the influence of the measuring device on the slits destroys the states of the particles. This is nothing special for electrons, but could be a surprise in the case of photons.

Suppose an electron is entangled with the polarizer and its spin is aligned. The electron passes through a grid that is properly aligned and through which it passes. If, as a measuring instrument, a magnetic field is placed in front of one of the slits of the grid, the electron is affected and the entanglement is destroyed.

Doing the same with an photon the result is the same. The intensity distribution on the screen is blurry or completely destroyed. Since nor electric, nor magnetic fields could influence the photon, the conclusion could only be, that the slits were influenced.

As you may know, X-ray spectroscopy is based on the periodicity of the atomic layers of crystals. We should also apply this knowledge to the edges of the slit material. The static electric and magnetic field pattern of the bound electrons on the surface of the slits is influenced by the instrument, and these,periodic in space, fields interact with the photon with its periodic space and time field components.

You see, I was a little free to think your question about a particle between entangled particles to the end. Thanks for the inspiration. Good question.

Comment: I wouldn’t say the slits are influenced or that electric and magnetic fields have anything to do with diffracting the photons. Photons will diffract based on proximity to the slit edge and gravity, in the same way gravity deflects all photons everywhere. patterns can easily be derived using this method as long as you consider the frequency/oscillation of the photon as it travels from the edge to the screen.

Comment: @Bill It’s nice to have alternative explanation for the “not understandable, one has to believe it” behaviour of the “interference” of light. But

Comment: Of course I have a but. Gravity is a not polarising field and does not interact with E and B fields. The geodesic path is due to mass-energy-interaction (simply gravity) and cannot explain the fringes. For this in my understanding it is necessary to take in account the E and B fields of the surfaces electrons and the photons. Anyway, without the educated scientists non of our guests have a chance to get proofed.

Comment: I said the photons do not influence the SLIT. But the edges DO influence the polarization of the photons. That is separate from the defraction of the photons. The combination of both along with photon frequency/oscillation will derive the interference patterns we observe.