# How to explain interference of light by Huygens' principle?

Tags: optics, visible-light, interference, huygens-principle

there was an almost the same question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144339/), but there was no appropriate answer(the answer there was incomplete and not to the point). now there is an updated answer to the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Huygens Principle explain interference?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/144339/)

Comment: this does not answer my question.

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate. You're saying it is the same question. It also has answers. This does not legitimate to ask the same question again.

Comment: @panic  I just added an answer to the linked question 144339 that I think will answer your question. Let me know.  I agree with you that the previous answers did not get the job done.

Comment: @panic  You should edit your question explaining why the answers to the other question do not answer your question (which they do not); and then flag it for moderator intervention to reopen it.

Comment: @user45664 your answer was exactly what I was expecting. thanks.

Comment: Neither idea/theory describes whats physically going on. They don't even try. I at least make an attempt in my paper "Single Edge Certainty" at   billalsept.com

Comment: Your question from another point of view https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/558551/particle-between-entangled-particles

Comment: And a added a new answer, not here, because closed, but for the linked question.